# How to circumvent checker framework type.invalid error?

Tags: java, checker-framework

We have a library we've written and after introducing the Checker Framework NullnessChecker to verify its code, it fails to compile (as expected). I've fixed all the obvious errors, but this one I cannot find out how to fix...

Here's the offending function's signature:

```
private static @Nullable char[] getChars(char ch)
```

And the call site where the error occurs:

```
@Nullable char[] replacement = getChars( string.charAt( index ) );
```

Can anyone tell me how to get checker to accept this? It seems to me to be correct code.

**EDIT**

The error:

```
[type.invalid] [@Initialized, @Nullable] may not be applied to the type "@Initialized @Nullable char"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message

```
[@Initialized, @Nullable] may not be applied to the type "@Initialized @Nullable char"
```

would have been clearer if it had just been

```
@Nullable may not be applied to the type "char"
```

The issue is that `char` is a primitive type.  It doesn't make sense to speak of `@Nullable char` or `@NonNull char`.  Nullness is applicable only to object (non-primitive) types.  The same is true of initialization.

If you want to specify a nullable array of `char` -- that is, the variable `replacement` is either null or is an array of `char` -- then write it this way:

```
char @Nullable [] replacement = ...;
```

If you write

```
 @Nullable char [] replacement = ...;
```

then that is an array of `@Nullable char`.

This is a standard part of the Java type annotation syntax, and is not specific to the Checker Framework.  However, there is a [FAQ](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-array-syntax-meaning) about this in the [Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).